# css applying style element to part of the children

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating the page in which elements with classes "question" and "answer" are being created dynamically, and they appear one inside the other (so the first question div contains answer divs, which contain following questions and so on), and I want them to have different border color, for example red one for questions and blue one for answers, but I can't just write them border-color property in my .css file because everything appears recursively and the last written property is as a result applied to all the elements. What could be the solution?

It looks something like this:

```
<div class="management">
        <button class="btn btn-primary addtree" type="button">Add new tree</button>
        <ul>
            <div id="new"></div>            
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ident = 0;
        var question;
        var answer;
        $.get('question', function(data){
                question = data;
        });
        $.get('answer', function(data){
                answer = data;
        });

        $(".management").on("click", ".addtree", function(){
            ident++; 
            $('#new').append(question);
            $('.question:last').attr('id',ident);
        });

        $(".management").on("click", ".addquestion", function(){ 
            ident++;
            $(this).parent().append(question);
            $(this).parent().children('.question').attr('id',ident);
            $(this).parent().children('.answer').css({"margin-left": "30px"});
            $(this).parent().children('.question').css({"margin-left": "30px"});
        });

        $(".management").on("click", ".addoption", function(){
                $(this).parent().append(answer);
                var currid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                $(this).parent().children('.answer').attr('id',ident);
                $(this).parent().children('.answer').css({"margin-left": "30px"});
                $(this).parent().children('.question').css({"margin-left": "30px"});
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Share your code please to make the problem more clear.

Comment: added html part, loaded question and answer are just divs with inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand you want something like this:

```css
.question {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.answer {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}


.question, .answer {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  Lorem ispum dolor sit amet

  <div class="answer">
    Color mit apsem
  </div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  Lorem ispum dolor sit amet

  <div class="answer">
    
    <div class="question">
      Lorem ispum dolor sit amet

      <div class="answer">
        Color mit apsem
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I need, I had the same code, but it wasn't working. So, the problem is probably somewhere else. Thank you!

UPD: welp, now it's working )) probably had been doing something wrong in the beginning